# How to create multiple variables dynamically that can be summed up

Tags: javascript, variables, dynamic, price

I have a variable that gets its value once an ID is clicked, via `.innerText`

```
var currentID = e.target.id;
```

I need the value of this variable, `currentID`, to be stored in a new variable which is named just like the ID of which it got its value.

So, if a user clicks an element with the ID `price1`, and the price is 200.
A new variable with the name price1 with value 200 should be created.

Then, I want to sum up the new variables: price1+price2+price3 etc = totalprice.

This is what I'm doing right now:

```
$('div.unselected-option').click(function(e) {
   $(this).toggleClass("selected-option unselected-option")

if ($(this).hasClass("selected-option")) {
   var currentID = e.target.id;
   console.log(currentID);
   var price1 = document.getElementById(currentID).innerText

   var finalprice
   finalprice = +price1;
   document.getElementById("showprice2").innerHTML = finalprice
```

Here's an image of the design:

[image: Here's an image of the design]

I can't seem to figure this out... What I'm doing right now just results in having 1 variable which means I cannot sum anything up... I would love your view on this issue!

Comment: If you want to create a new variable each time a user clicks on a element you could have a list and add a new value or object to that list. But please provide more code information (HTML) to help you with the solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your use case is pretty strange I hope your backend is secured and well made.

Here is a potential solution:

```
<div id="a1" onclick="handleProductClick">20</div>
<div id="a2" onclick="handleProductClick">40</div>
<div id="b1" onclick="handleProductClick">20</div>
<div id="b2" onclick="handleProductClick">60</div>
...
<div id="total-price">0</div>
...
const basket = {}

function addToBasket(event) {
  const { id, innerText } = event.target
  const price = parseInt(innertText, 10)
  const product = basket[id] 
  const count = product.count || 1
  basket[id] = {
    price,
    count
  }
}

function getBasketTotalPrice = () => {
  return Object.keys(basket)
   .reduce((total, product) => total + product.count * product.price, 0)
}

function handleProductClick = (event) => {
  addToBasket(event)
  const totalPrice = getBasketTotalPrice()
  document.querySelector('#total-price').innerHTML = totalPrice
}
```

Comment: I have 2 questions: 1, how would i display the total price into the element with the id 'showprice2'. 2: I need this to be toggle-able, so that prices can be removed from the basket as well.. I dont see how this does that.

Comment: I added an image to show what i'm trying to realise. I need the price to show up only when the boxes are selected, and they can be unselected as well.

Comment: I updated my answer. If your web site is really dynamic you should consider using a views/components framework lib. The easiest to handle for beginner is VueJS. Later, when you will be comfortable with Javascript React will be a good choice. If you are really motivated about learning javascript you can watch funfunfunction show (youtube). Remember Mozilla documentation is the best one (check array and object prototypes first).